# Pointers, struct and malloc()

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, variable-assignment

I've made this simple program to test `struct`, pointers and `malloc()` of C programming:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 typedef struct l {
    unsigned val;
    struct l * next;
} list;


typedef struct cont {
    list ** mat;
    unsigned riga;
} container;


int main(){

    container * c = (container *)malloc(sizeof(container));
    c->riga = 3;
    c->mat = (list**)malloc(sizeof(list*)*3);

    for(int i = 0; i<3 ;i++){
        c->mat[i] = NULL;
    }

    c->mat[0] = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
    c->mat[0]-> val = 4;
    c->mat[0]-> next = NULL;

    printf("val row 0: %d\n", c->mat[0]->val);

    /*************************/

    list * ca = c->mat[1];
    ca = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
    ca->val = 2;
    ca->next = NULL;

    printf("val row 1: %d\n", c->mat[1]->val);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I get a segfault on the 2nd `printf()` ... shouldn't `c->mat[1]` and `ca` be equivalent?

Shouldn't they point to the same allocated memory?

Initially `c->mat[1]` is `NULL` so is `ca = c->mat[1] = NULL`, after `ca= malloc()` it points to something else ... what about `c->mat[i]`? And what if I do the viceversa?

Comment: How about trying it yourself by perhaps printing the values or with a debugger? You'll find out.

Comment: [do not cast the return value of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Change `c->mat[1]` to be `ca` and it'll work as expected. You allocated to `ca` not to `c->mat[1]`. This initialisation `list * ca = c->mat[1];` is useless as in the next line you overwrite `ca`'s value.

Comment: And BTW, you'd do everybody a favour increasing readability of your code by indenting it properly!-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ca` is a copy of `c->mat[1]`, so when you later change `ca` to point to the malloc-ed list it is not a copy of `c->mat[1]` anymore and especially if you modify `ca` you do not also modify `c->mat[1]`.

If `ca` were not a pointer but an `int` you would not expect that, or would you assume that a was 2 in the following example?

```
int a = 3;
int ca = a;
ca = 2;
```

Of course, if `ca` is a copy of `c->mat[1]` and you change `*c` then you also change `*(c->mat[1])`.

Answer (score 2):

```
list * ca = c->mat[1];
```

set ca to NULL

```
ca = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
```

set ca to point to the new memory given from malloc, but c->mat[1] still point to NULL.

you can have a pointer to the pointer c->mat[1]:

```
list ** ca = &c->mat[1];
(*ca) = malloc(sizeof(list));
(*ca)->val = 2;
(*ca)->next = NULL;
```

and don't forget to use free().

Answer (score 1):

The code for `c->mat[0]` is correct, and could be used for `c->mat[1]`.

Or you code fix the `c->mat[1]` code by assigning the results of `malloc` to `c->mat[1]` and then copy the pointer to `ca`

```
c->mat[1] = malloc(sizeof(list));
list *ca = c->mat[1];
ca->val = 2;
ca->next = NULL;
```

Another solution is to copy `ca` to `c->mat[1]` at the end

```
list *ca = malloc(sizeof(list));
ca->val = 2;
ca->next = NULL;
c->mat[1] = ca;
```